# how to check if pandas dataframe cell contains zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing a for loop to go thorugh a series in my dataframe. I want to say that if both cells are zero, skip. I have to skip because i want to plot the output but when they 2 cells 'cost' and 'new_cost' is zero, it will give me an error:

data:

```
cost   new_cost
100.00  25.00
0.00     0.00
3.00    10.00
```

`TypeError: Empty 'Series': no numeric data to plot`

This is mycode:

```
if df.cost.isempty and df.new_cost.isempty:
    continue
else:
  .
```

This also didnt work:

```
if df[df.cost==0.00] and df[df.new_cost==0.00]:
    continue
else:
```

But now i am getting `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: isempty doesn't exist on a Series. And you are not looping through the cells of the series here. What is the content of your df?

Comment: Can you post the output from `df.info()` are you sure your dtypes are numeric and not strings?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to filter your dataframe before performing your loop (note that you have to enclose your boolean conditions in brackets inside the indexer):

```
df_filtered = df[(df.cost != 0) & (df.new_cost != 0)]
```